# The Dual of Space of normally convergent power series.

Tags: power-series, banach-spaces, banach-algebras, dual-spaces

one considers the Banach-$*$-Algebra (involution=conjugation, multiplication = pointwise multiplication):

$$A_r:=\{f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{C} \mid f=\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty f_m, \\ \|f\|_r < \infty\},$$

where the f_m are polynomials homgoeneous of degree m and
$$\|f\|_r =\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \|f_m\|_{\infty, \overline{B_r(0)}}$$
the series over the maximal norm of the f_n on the closed ball with radius r and center 0.

I would like to know, if somebody knows a description of the dual of this Banach space?

Best regards,
Dominik

Answer (score 1):

Your space is just the $\ell^1$ direct sum of the spaces $E_n$ formed by the homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$.  The dual is then the $\ell^\infty$ direct sum of the duals of the $E_n$.